How to pass data to execl correctly in C++?
I'm creating a C++ application, I need to execute dd. However instead of successfully runned dd i receive in terminal:
dd: unrecognized operand ' '$'\371''d'$'\230\200''Z'
// How I call this function
string output;
while ((output = execCommand("/usr/bin/dd", "dd", "if=/dev/zero", string("of=" + items[selectedItem].mountPoint + "/.file.bin").c_str(), "bs=1G", "count=1", "oflag=dsync")) == "") {}

I wrote my own function to execute program and obtain data from it. However, probably arguments are wrong given.
// My function for executing and obtaining data from program
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdarg>
#include <vector>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include "exec.hpp"

using namespace std;

string execCommand(string path, string program, string arguments, ...)
{
    va_list vaArguments;
    const char *argument;
    // path = "/usr/bin/dd"
    // program = "dd"
    vector<const char*> argumentsList;
    /*
      argumentsList[0] = "if=/dev/zero"
      argumentsList[1] = "of=/hereisareallongmountpoint/.file.bin"
      argumentsList[2] = "bs=1G"
      argumentsList[3] = "count=1"
      argumentsList[4] = "oflag=dsync"
      argumentsList[5] = nullptr
    */
    int result;
    int status;
    int pipeFd[2];
    FILE *commandOutput;
    char buffer[1024];
    string output;

    va_start(vaArguments, arguments);

    while ((argument = va_arg(vaArguments, const char *)) != nullptr) {
        argumentsList.push_back(argument);
    }

    va_end(vaArguments);

    result = pipe(pipeFd);

    if (result < 0) {
        cerr << "Error creating pipe for executing program" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    result = fork();

    if (result < 0) {
        cerr << "Error creating child process for executing program" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    if (result == 0) {
        dup2(pipeFd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(pipeFd[0]);
        close(pipeFd[1]);

        argumentsList.push_back(nullptr);

        execl(path.c_str(), program.c_str(), argumentsList.data());

        _exit(1);
    }

    close(pipeFd[1]);

    commandOutput = fdopen(pipeFd[0], "r");

    if (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), commandOutput)) {
        output += buffer;
    }

    wait(&status);

    return output;
}

How I can handle it in C++ to give to dd valid arguments? I don't have any ideas how to deal with it. Thanks in advance for any responses.

Maybe first remove your huge execCommand function, and run execl with some hardcoded values to see if it does what you need. Then proceed with your implementation, and debug your code

With hardcoded values it does what I need, but I need wrap this in function

Good, then it's easy to compare the correct hardcoded values with your path.c_str(), program.c_str(), argumentsList.data().

If you have an array of strings, execl is not the appropriate hammer for you. You almost have the right arguments for execv, just move program into the list as arg0 and you should be good to go.

This question is similar to: Difference between exec, execvp, execl, execv?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
